# issue with standard checkbox and image

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

## Question:

why I am not seeing the image appear when I click on the checkbox?

#### Problem:

I get no errors with Inspect Tools.  Does anyone see something I am missing?  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #your_img {
       display: none;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#show_image').on("click", function() {
          if ($('#your_img').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#your_img').show();
          } else {
            $('#your_img').hide();
          }
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show_image">Show Image</input>
    <div id="your_img">
    <img src="https://saltwx.com/images/chloro/chloro_bar.png" alt="A image" style="height: 
    485px;width:71px">
    </div>
    <body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your click event is getting registered before the checkbox is rendered in dom. Your click event should get registered after the checkbox is rendered in dom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #your_img {
       display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show_image">Show Image</input>
    <div id="your_img">
    <img src="https://saltwx.com/images/chloro/chloro_bar.png" alt="A image" style="height: 
    485px;width:71px">
    </div>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#show_image').on("click", function() {
          if ($('#your_img').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#your_img').show();
          } else {
            $('#your_img').hide();
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a clear mistake with the body tag! You opened it after all the div and stuff.
Here's the fixed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #your_img {
       display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#show_image').on("click", function() {
          if ($('#your_img').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#your_img').show();
          } else {
            $('#your_img').hide();
          }
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show_image">Show Image</input>
        <div id="your_img">
        <img src="https://saltwx.com/images/chloro/chloro_bar.png" alt="A image" style="height: 
        485px;width:71px">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your div elements and logic code in the body section. All the logic code is placed before the ending of the body section. The last script section containing your logic compiles after the dom is ready.

You can use the below code. Hope it helps!!!

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #your_img {
           display: none;
            }

        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <input type="checkbox" id="show_image">Show Image</input>
          <div id="your_img">
          <img src="https://saltwx.com/images/chloro/chloro_bar.png" alt="A image" style="height: 
        485px;width:71px">
        </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#show_image').on("click", function() {
              if ($('#your_img').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#your_img').show();
              } else {
                $('#your_img').hide();
              }
            });
          </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```